# Scroll element to anchor 75% of the screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky

This might seem a little convoluted - I am attempting to build a function

I am trying to create a sticky scroll function when the Y-axis reaches a certain height percentage of the single-post-container. The sidebar itself is quite long, essentially when you reach to the bottom on the article - the comments section. The single-post-container sticks to the top and the sidebar has fixed scrolling

Below is a snippet of my attempts do create the function

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 800) {
    $('.sidebar-fixed').addClass('test');
    $('.single-post-container').addClass('single-post-fixed');
} else {
    $('.sidebar-fixed').removeClass('test');
    $('.single-post-container').removeClass('single-post-fixed');
}

});
```

Comment: Your snippet is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's this very old jQuery plugin that does what you need, I still use it all the time. It's called [stickyfloat](https://github.com/yairEO/stickyfloat).

[Here's](http://yaireo.github.io/stickyfloat/) a demo to see what it does. I think  `$('.single-post-container').stickyfloat({duration: 0});` should solve your problem. You can even add an option for the start offset that you need. This offset should be the height of your `.single-post-container` minus the height of the window. That way, the scrolling starts when the bottom of the article is on screen.

This practically inverts the definition of the sidebar. The main article becomes the sidebar that scrolls next to the actual sidebar, which defines the height of the entire page. The best thing about this plugin is that you can add a header and footer to your site, and the fixed content will not overlap, but stop right at the footer.

Answer (score -1):

There is a relatively new CSS property `position: sticky;` which will do what you need, but browser support is a bit lacking: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Simply give your `.single-post` or any element in your content `position: sticky;` and when it reaches the top of the viewport it will hold its position as if fixed without needing javascript.